# Laravel can't find class

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm learning Laravel but some things aren't how they suppose to be I guess. When I'm trying to add something to the database with a model (the model has the name of the table). I receive the error:

> FatalErrorException in C:\wamp\www\app\Http\Controllers\blog.php line
>   23:
>
> > Class 'App\models\posts' not found

This is mij blog.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use View;
use App\models\posts;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;



    class blog extends Controller
    {
       public function newPost() 
       {
          return View::make('new');
       }

       public function createPost() 
       {
            $posts = new posts();
            $posts->title = Input::get('title');
            $posts->content = nl2br(Input::get('content'));
            $posts->save();
           // return Redirect::route('viewpost',array('id' => $post->id));
       }
    }
```

So my posts class is in the App\models folder. Why is laravel telling me it can't find it? When I create an object within php artisan and add things it's received well in the database.

Comment: Is the case correct? If you're on anything other than windows, paths/namespaces are case sensitive.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I'm using windows.

Comment: Do you have `namespace App\models;` in your model?

Comment: Show the code for your `posts` class as well.

Comment: In standard eloquent models are named as if they are one ex: `Post` and the table would be lowercase plural ex: `posts` if you have not changed the `$tableName` in your model this might cause conflicts